# Creating a String constant which contains a single null character

Tags: c#, string, null

I use a Char constant declared like this as a separator to split and join strings on:

```
public const Char DELIMITERCHAR = (char)0;
```

However, I am often required to cast the char to string, for example when using replace like this:

```
someString.Replace(DELIMITERCHAR.ToString(), "someOtherDelimiter-String");
```

So, in order to avoid using ToString() I'd like to have a *String* constant too which contains nothing more than a null character, but I can't find out how to create it...

Doing the following does not seem right, since I want a string which contains null, not one that *is* null:

```
public const String DELIMITERSTR = null;
```

These approaches do not work either, since they are not "constant" enough:

```
public const String DELIMITERSTR = DELIMITERCHAR.ToString();
public const String DELIMITERSTR = ((char)0).ToString();
```

The result is, obviously, a compiler error saying: "The expression being assigned to 'DELIMITERSTR' must be constant.'

Seems this should silly-simple, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Would string.Empty not work?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. That will give an empty string, not one that contains a null character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply declare a one-character-length string with `\0` as the only char:

```
public const String DELIMITERSTR = "\0";
```

Then, you will always be able to extract this char from it, if necessary:

```
DELIMITEDSTR[0]
```

Comment: Aah... using the escape backslash of course. I knew it was simple... Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Strictly to your question Yeldar answer is right.

But, if we think a little bit more, we may consider that NULL characters may cause problems in a lot of situations, since this character may be refused in some databases or applications - even because it is considered as an international symbol for end-of-data and so forth.

If you accept an advise, try to consider another symbol as delimeter, like "|" or ASCII-255, or a group of symbols (like "|:"). It can be safer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. We use the null character because it is highly unlikely to exist in the data we process, i.e. it is not something users tend to accidentally write in a textbox. Pipe "|" is on the keyboard so we won't use that. =) ASCI255 could be an option, will consider it. Thanks!